# Use the result of a QR code scan to open an image in a new android activiy

Tags: android, imageview, zxing

I have a program for an android application which has 2 activies MainActivity and CarteActivity. I have a button on the MainActivity layout (activity_main.xml) which launches a QR code scanner (already programmed using zxing). The second activity layout (activity_carte.xml) has an ImageView which code is :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/carte0" />
```

`

In my drawable folder I copied some pictures named carte1, carte2, carte3...

I also generated a few qrcodes which result is also carte1, carte2, carte3... (as a text)

Now I want that when I scan these qrcodes, the CarteActivity appears and the ImageViewer displays the picture corresponding to the code (when i scan the code which returns carte1 as a result, the picture carte1 appears in the ImageViewer), but I don't know how to.

I noticed that in the MainActivity the result of the scan is memorized in the string "contents" :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {               
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);

            // Handle successful scan
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
    }
```

`

But I don't know how to use it properly.

Could you help me with that ? I'm sure it's not that hard but I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your MainActivity call ass follows

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {               
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);

            // Handle successful scan
            Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarteActivity.class);
            startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("QRContents",  contents);
            startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);

        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

Then do changes on CarteActivity as follows

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CarteActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carte);

        Intent bgIntent = getIntent();
                String contents = bgIntent.getStringExtra("QRContents");
                ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                if(contents.equals("carte1")){
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.carte1);
                }
                if(contents.equals("carte2")){
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.carte2);
                }
                if(contents.equals("carte3")){
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.carte3);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(CarteActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);

        }
}
```

Comment: I actually found out just before seeing your answer, but thank you for answering quickly. I didn't do the exact same thing but the idea is the same, I just declared public the string contents and used it to set conditions in the CarteActivity like you did. I also add a condition if contents.startsWith("carte") so that when the user scans another code (for example to go on a website), the CarteActivity doesn't appear.

Comment: After a few tests, your way works better than mine but I still have a problem : when i start the app and scan for the first time, everything works, but when i go back to the main activity and try to scan another time, the scanner displays the text of the qr code but the CarteActivity doesn't appear ...

Comment: Override the `onBackPressed` method as I added to your CarteActivity class.